# Problems with scroll in listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a custom adapter to fill a `ListView` with a name and a number. If that number have a specific valor, this number have a different color.
When it display it works fine but when I scroll the list other numbers that don’t have the conditions also obtain the color. This is the custom adapter and the `getView()` method.

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CategoriaD> {

    private ArrayList<CategoriaD> elementList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<CategoriaD> elementList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, elementList);
        this.elementList = new ArrayList<CategoriaD>();
        this.elementList.addAll(elementList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView texto;
        TextView cantidad;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_inspeccion_categoria, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.texto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texto);
            holder.cantidad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.estadistica);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        CategoriaD Elemento = elementList.get(position);
        holder.texto.setText(Elemento.getNombre());
        holder.cantidad.setText(Elemento.getEstadistica());
        if(Elemento.getEstadistica().equals(“50”)){
            holder.cantidad.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        holder.cantidad.setTag(Elemento);

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    if(Elemento.getEstadistica().equals(“50”)){
        holder.cantidad.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

You need to make sure you have an else statement to set your color back to the default you had because when using convert views when a change is made it persists because the view won't be reinflated.

```
if(Elemento.getEstadistica().equals(“50”)){
    holder.cantidad.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else {
    //TODO change to your default color color
    holder.cantidad.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

EDIT: Also, your change is small so this is better than inflating 2 separate convertViews, but if you had more dramatic changes to the convertView per item or many more items, then you could override the getItemViewType(int) method and that would allow you to inflate a different convert view for each type of item and automatically reuse it whenever the right item type was requested. You would just have it output and integer dependent on the same if else case that you're using to change the text color. (Probably a 0 and 1 respectively.)

[Adapter getItemViewType(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

In case of Custom Adapters, I find that covering all bases is the way to go. An if-block should have a complementing else-block, even if it seems redundant.

Try the following `getView()` method in place of yours:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_inspeccion_categoria, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.texto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texto);
        holder.cantidad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.estadistica);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    CategoriaD Elemento = elementList.get(position);
    holder.texto.setText(Elemento.getNombre());
    holder.cantidad.setText(Elemento.getEstadistica());
    if(Elemento.getEstadistica().equals(“50”)){
        holder.cantidad.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        holder.cantidad.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);    // Change this to whatever Color
    }

    holder.cantidad.setTag(Elemento);

    return convertView;

}
```